# tensorflow graph node names dont match operation names

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, import, operation

I am a newer for tensorflow, and I am confused with the graph struction in tensorflow tutorial label_image . Using the code blew:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with open('/var/tmp/feng/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        print graph_def
```

I can see the graph struction as this

```
...
...
node {
  name: "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1"
  op: "Reshape"
  input: "InceptionV3/Predictions/Softmax"
  input: "InceptionV3/Predictions/Shape"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "Tshape"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
}
```

It's OK. I can see the last node name is "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1",however, when I use code blew to show all operations

```
the operation in this graph
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        # results = sess.run(output_tensor, {
        #     input_tensor: t
        # })
        print(sess.graph.get_operations())
```

It shows me like this

```
 <tf.Operation 'import/InceptionV3/Predictions/Softmax' type=Softmax>,
 <tf.Operation 'import/InceptionV3/Predictions/Shape' type=Const>, 
 <tf.Operation 'import/InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1' type=Reshape>
```

why the operation name add import before the node name.It's strange because the string import never appears in the graph of this model.I google it but everyone says the function

```
get_operation_by_name
```

return an instance of type **tf.Operation**,which is a node in the computational graph, so the difference between operation name and node name is confused. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably, you imported the graph using [import_graph_def](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) or some higher-level function that ends up calling `import_graph_def`. Here is a copy of documentation for its `name` argument:

```
name: (Optional.) A prefix that will be prepended to the names in 
      graph_def. Note that this does not apply to imported function 
      names. Defaults to "import".
```

If you don't want any prefix added, invoke it with `name=''`

Comment: Thank you so much. You answer my bewilderment for a week

Comment: glad I could help